# mysql loggin slow queries

Tags: mysql, indexing, join

I ran the mysqltuner script recently and i noticed around 5000 joins done without indexes, this has to be reduced to a small value.

There is an option that allows us to log these queries in mysql

i have added the following lines under [mysqld] section of my.cnf

log-queries-not-using-indexes
log_slow_queries=/var/log/mysqld.slow.log

But the logs still remains empty, how can i get the logging to work in order to optimize those queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you restart MySQL after doing this?

`sudo service mysql restart`

If you didn't, it won't log anything.  I've also wondered myself if there's a delay in when it actually logs queries.  Give it time, the logs will show up.

Comment: The logging is now working, i observed the logs and noticed that most of the queries logged were for joins on tables that have a field status which toggles between 2 values 0 or 1.  I had read some time back that indexes on such fields are not required as the range is very less.